# java with Amazon AWS NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, windows, amazon-s3

java with Amazon AWS NoSuchFieldError

Here is the console log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URLEncodedUtils.java:246)
at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URLEncodedUtils.java:225)
at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.parseQuery(URIBuilder.java:95)
at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.digestURI(URIBuilder.java:165)
at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.<init>(URIBuilder.java:90)
at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils.rewriteURI(URIUtils.java:138)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.rewriteRequestURI(DefaultRequestDirector.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:476)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:837)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3826)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3778)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:610)
at net.pocketsurvey.cloud.Amazon.listObjectsInBucket(Amazon.java:93)
```

The bottom line is where my code hands over to Amazon's S3. The code is as follows:

```
public static ObjectListing listObjectsInBucket(String bucketName,
  String key) throws Exception {
  ObjectListing list = null;
  AmazonS3Client client = Client.s3(Client.DESKTOP);
  try {
    boolean b_exists = client.doesBucketExist(bucketName);
    boolean o_exists = client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, key);
    if(b_exists) {
      list = client.listObjects(bucketName, key);
    }
  } catch ( AmazonServiceException e){
    String  err =  e.getErrorMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch ( AmazonClientException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch ( Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return list;
  }
```

'client.listObjects' is where it bombs out.

libraries used include:
  aws-java-sdk-1.10.77.jar
  httpclient-osgi-4.3.jar
  org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.2.1.jar

'b_exists' is true but 'o_exists' returns as false even tho the key most definitely exists.

I am using credentials that work for other things such as email, and downloading a known object, i.e. a complete key string. But trying to get a listing using a partial key string (such as "hhs/") I get the above eror.

Also the 'catches' don't catch it.

The code currently runs on the UI thread but I have tried it on its own thread with similar results.

The platform is Windows 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem sorted - library mismatch.

'aws-java-sdk-1.10.77.jar' needs 'org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.4.4.jar' to bein the build path.

Comment: how do we get to know this from documentation? @Mike Lima

Comment: same problem but use s3 with java SDK, thanks

Comment: how to find what version of httpcomponents is needed